# Is there a Pandas function to highlight a week's 10 lowest values in a time series?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

Rookie here so please excuse my question format:

I got an event time series dataset for two months (columns for "date/time" and "# of events", each row representing an hour).

I would like to highlight the 10 hours with the lowest numbers of events for each week. Is there a specific Pandas function for that? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [User guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html) and the documentation practicing the examples. It will give you a better idea of what is available to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a dataframe `df` with column `col` as well as a `datetime` column.

You can simply sort the column with

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],
                   'datetime' : ['2019-01-01 00:00:00','2015-02-01 00:00:00','2015-03-01 00:00:00','2015-04-01 00:00:00',
                  '2018-05-01 00:00:00','2016-06-01 00:00:00','2017-07-01 00:00:00','2013-08-01 00:00:00',
                  '2015-09-01 00:00:00','2015-10-01 00:00:00','2015-11-01 00:00:00','2015-12-01 00:00:00',
                  '2014-01-01 00:00:00','2020-01-01 00:00:00','2014-01-01 00:00:00']})
df = df.sort_values('col')
df = df.iloc[0:10,:]
df
```

Output:

```
    col datetime
0   1   2019-01-01 00:00:00
1   2   2015-02-01 00:00:00
2   3   2015-03-01 00:00:00
3   4   2015-04-01 00:00:00
4   5   2018-05-01 00:00:00
5   6   2016-06-01 00:00:00
6   7   2017-07-01 00:00:00
7   8   2013-08-01 00:00:00
8   9   2015-09-01 00:00:00
9   10  2015-10-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, but what I got is "datetime" rows per each hour and "col" represents a number of unique events. With that, I would like to find the 10 hours per calendar week with the 10 lowest "cal" values.

Answer (score 0):

<s>I know there's a function called nlargest. I guess there should be an nsmallest counterpart. [pandas.DataFrame.nsmallest](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nsmallest.html)</s>

```
df.nsmallest(n=10, columns=['col'])
```

My bad, so your DateTimeIndex is a Hourly sampling. And you need the hour(s) with least events weekly.

```
...
Date                 n_events
2020-06-06 08:00:00  3
2020-06-06 09:00:00  3
2020-06-06 10:00:00  2
...
```

Well I'd start by converting each hour into columns.
1. Create an Hour column that holds the hour of the day.

```
df['hour'] = df['date'].hour
```

2. Pivot the hour values into columns having values as n_events.

So you'll then have 1 datetime index, 24 hour columns, with values denoting #events. [pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)

```
...
Date       hour0 ... hour8 hour9 hour10 ... hour24
2020-06-06 0         3     3     2          0
...
```

Then you can resample it to weekly level aggregate using sum.

```
df.resample('w').sum()
```

The last part is a bit tricky to do on the dataframe. But fairly simple if you just need the output.

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    print(sorted(row[1:]))
```

Comment: Thanks! Any ideas how to modify that function to output "nsmallest" per calendar week?